# Non Blocking Socket Blocked by fgets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, fcntl

I'm testing things out and i made a non blocking socket but the "fgets" ruined my plans. How can i prevent fgets for blocking out my while loop showing below?
A code that solves this would be greatly appreciated.

```
fcntl(clientSocket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

while(1){

     fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
     send(clientSocket,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);

     recv(clientSocket,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
     printf("%s",buffer);

}
```

Comment: `fgets()` is blocking on `stdin`. This has nothing to do with your non-blocking socket whatsoever. Look into `select` and `poll`/`epoll`.

Comment: if fgets() didn't block, what do you plan to do next  - i.e. if there was no inut from fgets, what do you want to send ?

Comment: i want to have an input, but without blocking upcoming messages from recv. Imagine something like a Chat service between client and Server

Comment: Then you are asking a wrong question.

Comment: You can use two threads, one for `fgets` and `send`, the other one for `recv` and `printf`

Answer (score -1):

It's not recommended, but if you want you can just do:

```
if (fcntl(0, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) == -1) {
   perror("fcntl");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

And you have a non blocking stdin.

Hint: better use select or poll for waiting ready file descriptor.